# Confusion matrix of 3*2

Tags: machine-learning, prediction, confusion-matrix

I would like to include confusion matrix in my research report. I have a binary classification problem. The positive class is further divided into two types for example: Real Positive and Obstruction Positive.

Can I plot it in a 3by2 way to indicate the positive class division ? If I consider 3by3 case, there are some empty rows which mean nothing. I am attaching both the pictures. Which one is more appropriate?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Does your classifier predict positive/negative or real/obstructed/negative?

Comment: @Dave It will predict negative and positive only(binary classification), but I further divided positive into two types for displaying confusion matrix

Comment: The first option is more appropriate since the classifier doesn't distinguish between actual vs. obstructed positive.